# Transferencia de stock en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo el siguiente problema, trato de hacer una transferencia de stock entre bodegas tengo una tabla llamada productos_bodega la cual se conforma por

- id_producto
- id_bodega
- stock

En esa tabla hago mis movimientos por ejemplo entradas y salidas pero quisiera hacer traslados de stock entre bodegas, para hacer estos movimientos hice un select para bodega otro para producto y un campo para agregar stock lo que no he podido hacer es los traslados este es el codigo con que trate resolver

```
function trasladoStock(Request $request){
    $product_entrante = productos_bodega::where('id_bodega', '=', $request->id_bodega_entrante)->where('id_producto', '=', $request->id_producto)->first();
    if($product_entrante){
      $product_entrante->update(["stock" => $product->stock + $request->stock]);
    }
    $product_saliente = productos_bodega::where('id_bodega_saliente', '=', $request->id_bodega_saliente)->where('id_producto', '=', $request->id_producto)->first();
    if($product_saliente){
      $product_saliente->update(["stock" => $product->stock - $request->stock]);
    }
    return back();
  }
```

Al ejecutar no hubo ningún error pero tampoco hizo nada
Este es mi formulario[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi formulario tiene dos select uno para preguntar la bodega de dónde se va a sacar el stock y el otro de dónde se va a introducir el producto y el campo del stock de cuánto se va a trasladar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdón no sé si me hice explicar

Comment: Tu error está en esta línea: `productos_bodega::where('id_bodega_saliente'`, no existe esa columna, sólo debes poner `id_bodega`.

Comment: @JonatanLavado Muchas gracias si me funciono asi